# Xcode 9 - clone from Bitbucket - how to change the username?

Tags: git, bitbucket, clone, xcode9

I've just added an app to a bitbucket repository from my old system. That worked fine, but I'm running into a problem cloning it to my new system, a MacBook Pro running Xcode 9.  To clone it, I've followed these steps so far:

```
1. Open Xcode, select "Source Control", then "Clone". 
2. Paste the bitbucket address into the address.
3. After the verification, it displays the address, type (git) and Login (defaults to "anonymous") 
4. Select "User name and Password" instead of "anonymous".
5. It displays a username which is the name of the project and grayed out, and a password.
6. Since I can't enter the username for my bitbucket account (my email address), I alway get an "authentication failed".
```

I've tried the following per some suggestions from google, but no luck so far:

```
git config --global user.name "myname"
git config --global user.email "myemail"

xcrun git config --global user.name 'myname'
xcrun git config --global user.email 'myemail'
```

Any ideas? I just need to be able to change the user name to clone it, but it's grayed out.

Comment: Which address are you pasting in? (Feel free to anonymize it.)

Comment: The address is the one given in the bitbucket site next to the download icon, which says "git clone https://myprojectname@bitbucket.org/myprojectnam/myappname.git". The name being supplied in the Xcode dialog box is "myprojectname", but that's not the name I sign into bitbucket with (which is my email addres). To be clear, the address I'm pasting is https://myprojectname@bitbucket.org/myprojectname/myappname.git, but I've also tried https://myprojectname@bitbucket.org/myprojectname/myappname and https://myprojectname@bitbucket.org/myprojectname with no luck.

Comment: The email address is not the username. The username is the username. Click your avatar icon on the left side and go to your profile; your username is whatever is after "bitbucket.org/".

Comment: So, my user name is the same as the project name, and that's what's being provided as the username in the Xcode dialog box. However, that's not the name I log into bitbucket with, so the authentication fails anyway. Do I have to change my login name/email address to match my username/projectname? How can Xcode authenticate if I don't provide my login name?

Comment: Is there a way I can grant my email address authorization to clone?

Comment: Your email address is not going to work with HTTPS authentication for Git or Mercurial. Use the username for XCode, and use the email address for any GUI things.

Alternately, SSH.

Comment: I was able to download the project via the command line, then open it in Xcode. However, when I try to push the change, I run into the same problem - the dialog box says "Enter your credentials for the repository "xxxxx" on host 'bitbucket.org'.  The login type defaults to username and password; the username is my project name, and when I enter the password I use for logging into bitbucket, it just prompts for the password.

Comment: Actually, I tried the commit and push, and this time it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant change your username because the URL you are cloning from starts with https://git@bitbucket.org ..

Try following these steps to clone a repo from bitbucket

1. Copy your repo link
2. Open XCode -> Project from source control
3. A dialog box opens, paste the url in the text box
4. Remove your username from the link so that the url to the repo is something like https://bitbucket.org ...
5. Enter your username and password
6. Profit